# PyBrain Deprecation Warning

Tags: python, numpy, warnings, pybrain, deprecation-warning

I am getting deprecation warning whenever I call the `splitWithProportion()` function in PyBrain. Below is the Warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.1-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py:45: DeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
  return self.getField(field)[seq[index]:]
```

Does anyone knows how to solve this? From my reading, this could be a problem from the numpy library. I am running numpy 1.9. The warning only occurs when I use the pybrain sequential data set. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem does not lie with PyBrain at all. I am using pybrain dataset to be fed into a confusion matrix frm scikit-learn. The deprecation problem is with the scikit learn confusion_matrix class. So, if you are using the confusion matrix of the 0.14 version of scikit-learn, you may encounter this error. I upgraded my version of scikit-learn to 0.15 and the problem vanishes.